# Rails3 static controller not finding the actual static page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

It is probably understood that I am pretty new to Rails without me even mentioning it :)

So I have a static controller which is working.  Here is the route:

```
match "/pages/:page" => "pages#team"
```

And I am able to confirm that this route is working because this controller code outputs things to the console:

```
def team
  print("Output some test code to see if system gets here\n") 
end
```

What I am trying to do is have the controller redirect to a view page that I made.  My view page is: team.html.rb and it is located at /app/views/pages/team.html.rb

How can I make the controller redirect there?

Thanks!

Comment: it's probably because your html should be erb instead of just rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have an action in `pages` for team

```
#in PagesController
def team
end
```

Then rename your file to:
`team.html.erb`

Comment: Oh yeah that typo totally fixed things :))))

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, you may want to checkout highvoltage from thoughbot for handling static pages:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage